# Questions about Varnish and magento 2

Tags: magento2, varnish

- Is it true that varnish doesn't work with HTTPS?
- Is there an alternative that works well with magento 2? For two reasons, one I don't think it works with HTTPS, and two it's causing me too much trouble and breaking my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varnish openly does not support HTTPS, more about this can be found [here](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/phk/ssl_again.html)

There are multiple highly documented pages about Magento2 and Varnish as well as configuring Varnish for Magento2 [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html)

The most common approach is to use a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy)  that is introduce a "front man server" that talks to the internet over HTTPS and forwards the calls to the "worker server" over HTTP then returns the fetched result to the client.

Magento has a built in full page cache storage. That is, it uses the filesystem. You can configure that from Admin > Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System > Full Page Cache > Built-In-Cache. The performance is considerably different as one could imagine

Comment: Is there a docker image ready for deployment configured in this way? BTW I didn't find any magento docker image that is maintained, except one belonging to magento cloud, not sure if I could deploy it or if I have to use magento cloud

Comment: Deploy on production? I don't think there is a production ready docker env for Magento 2 available. At least I have not found one as of yet.

Comment: Is there any varnish alternatives for magento? If not how much worse would magento 2 be if I don't use varnish? Varnish is causing trouble, I'd like to avoid it if possible

Comment: Magento has a built in full page cache storage. That is, it uses the filesystem. You can configure that from Admin > Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System > Full Page Cache > Built-In-Cache. The performance is considerably different as one could imagine.

Answer (score 1):

1. varnish itself not working with ssl. configure [ssl terminator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS_termination_proxy) in front
2. if you have small traffic shop with little orders you can safely use file cache.

varnish cache is a must have for high traffic shops.